# How do I loop through mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of 100k domains and its tags. tags are separated with commas.

Due to UTF encoding problems some tags are in wierd characters. so I want to get rid of this.

so I want to loop through each domain in my database
then explode tag then filter it from unwanted characters
then insert it into new table.

my table looks like this...

```
    Domain          Tags
    yahoo.co.jp     yahoo,search,portal,japan,ãƒãƒ¼ã‚¿ãƒ«,æ¤œç´¢,news
    163.com         news,é—¨æˆ·,æ–°é—»,portal,ç½‘æ˜“,163,china,é—¨æˆ·ç 
    qq.com          qq,china,portal,news,im,é—¨æˆ·,chinese,web,socialn...
```

Comment: 100k+ domains, 500k+ images... and not a single bit of knowledge. Why not to practice on not so great numbers first?

Comment: The question title should probably mention PHP.

Comment: I don't understand how you can insert 100k domains and you don't know how to select them in a for loop? or while loop?

Comment: @Lacroix my question isnt only for loop through but the same time filtering. I know how to loop through but I dont know how to filter this characters within the loop.

Comment: Wow, great comments guys, really helpful for the OP to know that he cannot count or use the most simple functions of MySQL. If you don't think this is a good question, downvote it. Why do you feel the need to criticize him?

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [tablename];";
$result  = mysql_query($query);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)
{
   $tags = explode($r["Tags"]);
   //Do your work here
   $newtags = FilterTags(",", $tags);
   $tagstring = implode(",", $newtags);
   $query = "INSERT INTO [NewTableName] (`Domain`, `Tags`) VALUES (\"".$r["Domain"]."\", \"".$tagstring."\")";
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Coding without IDE is kinda strange ;-)

Comment: not syntax error (I don't have an syntax analyzer in my browser either), but a fundamental error. There is a rule, regarding SQL syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it, could you help me a bit?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() <- ever heard of such a function?

Comment: @tokk col.shrapnel want to show his importance to everyone as this table isnt in public domain so we dont want to worry about MySQL injection atleast now.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel no need for this function here, nothing is inserted what hasn't been in a table before. That function should be used to filter users' content etc.

Comment: It makes me sad when I see an ignorance

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel It makes me sad, watching a guy who read once "mysql_real_escape_string() should be used" and who is not able to see that it is NOT neccessary in THIS context, downvoting all the answers and has no better suggestion himself.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I will admit to being ignorant on this, as I too thought that data that was just taken from the database was safe to put back in. Is this an incorrect assumption, and can you back that up? I'm usually a fan of your posts but this one is new to me, so I'd like to know.

Comment: @Andrew mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with security.

Comment: I realize that, it's to escape a query string. But if the data's already been escaped, by virtue of it being inserted into the database before, then why does it need to happen again?

Comment: @Andrew make a test. It will be better than 1000 words.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel see http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string : "If this function is not used to escape data, the query is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks." But in this case it should be impossible to happen.

Comment: `*sigh*` This manual page is wrong and misleading and should be totally rewritten.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel you won't give up, hmm?

Comment: @Everyone: Imagine you had inserted "test's" into the table. When you try to insert that back into the database, if you don't escape it again, it will mess up. Think about it. :)

Comment: @Drackir but it was escaped before inserting the first time, you get it escaped from the table, and there is no need to escape it again!

Comment: Also, escaping doesn't REMOVE the bad quotes, it just allows them to be entered. So the text is still bad and should be escaped, even if it's not malicious as in my example above (which will error your query).

Comment: @Tokk: It doesn't insert the escaped string into the table. It inserts it into the table as it is. The escaping is for the query not for the table.

Comment: Think of it this way, if the string was stored in the table with the extra escape values in it, wouldn't you have to unescape it to use it again? But you don't, the string is the same going in (before escaping) as it is coming out and therefore requires escaping to be put back in again.

Comment: @Andrew see - it works. It always does. A man speaking from experience worth 1000 lamers who just "read" [but didn't understand what they read].

Comment: Oh, good point. No, the words were much more valuable than a test would have been. Simply clarifying that escaping doesn't change the data, it just makes it safe for insertion was sufficient to open my eyes.

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $cleanstr = mysql_real_escape_string(cleanChars($row['Tags']));
    mysql_update("UPDATE mytable SET Tags = '$cleanstr' WHERE Domain = '$row[\'Domain\']");

}

function cleanChars($str) {
    //this function will explode the string and clean the chars
    //use implode after you clean the unwanted characters to convert the array to a string.
    return $cleanstr;
}
```